# Best way to attach and update properties using Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework

I have an action method that receives a list of items containing updated values, the thing is I only want to update a couple of fields (either email or phone) and not the full record. The code below seems to do what I need but is there a better or updated way to do this with EF 5? I sometimes see people using .Find instead of Attach etc.

```
        public ActionResult Update(IEnumerable<GenericTable> items)
        {
            using (var gEntities = new genericEntities())
            {
                foreach (var GenericTable in items)
                {
                gEntities.GenericTable.Attach(GenericTable);
                gEntities.Entry(GenericTable).Property(x => x.EmailAddress).IsModified = true;
                gEntities.Entry(GenericTable).Property(x => x.PhoneNumber).IsModified = true;


            }
            gEntities.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Here I am explicitly telling EF the email address AND phone number are modified each time but in practice it will one one or the other, is there a way to detect only the modified columns/properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach is fine for your purposes, unless you already have one of those GenericTable items in the context, in which case it'll throw an exception. 
Find searches for the entry in the context and if it doesn't find it, it queries the database for that entry and returns it (thus attaching it in the process).

I'd set the modified flag for the entire table like this:

```
foreach (var table in items)
{
    gEntities.GenericTable.Attach(table);
    gEntities.Entry<GenericTable>(table).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

EF will check which property is modified and update accordingly, when you call SaveChanges().